# heroku custom domain with cname for staging app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cname

I host my personal website on heroku with a custom domain name, pointing to my heroku app with cname.

I am doing the same thing for another app(as staging app) as staging.mywebsite.com.

The problem is that when I visit the original heroku url for my staging app it works fine, but when I visit staging.mywebsite.com "No such app" error shows up.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: when you have made these updates? It takes some time for server to refresh

Comment: It's been a month maybe! that's not the issue but thanks

Comment: have you added the staging subdomain to your heroku apps settings?

Comment: @fardin you welcome. If you need solving anything else just ask

Comment: YES!!!! I have no idea how I forgot that. Thanks

Comment: The above was just ironic, but your question could come in handy someone definitely . Make sure it has answer added so someone could look and find it.